# Why is my connection to my local mysql server so slow, while i query something with my sharded bot?

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

i want to connect my sharded discord bot to my local MySQL Database. But when i connected the 4 shards, the first 3 are so slow, it takes round about 20 seconds to execute `SELECT * FROM GeneralStats;`

This table has 1 row with 4 columns. So it shouldn't take so long.

My connection creator:

```
class Database {
constructor() {
    this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: ``,
        password: '',
        database: ''
    });
    this.connection.on('end', async (err) => {
        client.log('MYSQL', client.shard.ids[0] + ' connection end!');
    })
    this.connection.on('error', async (err) => {
        client.log('MYSQL', client.shard.ids[0] + ' connection errored! Error message: ' + err.message);
    })
}
query(sql) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.connection.query(sql, (err, rows) => {
            if (err)
                return reject(err);
            resolve(rows);
        });
    });
}
close() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.connection.end( err => {
            if (err)
                return reject(err);
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
}
```

Every shard is using a other user and password to connect. But i tried it with the same user, too.

Comment: Please post complete TEXT results of SHOW TABLE STATUS Like 'GeneralStats'; and last 50 lines of error log from any of the 3 instances you are connecting to with the delay.

Comment: The problem is, that there is no error log, it just needs round about 20 seconds in the shard 0 and shard 1, in shard 2 it takes round about 0.1 seconds.

Comment: If you would post from your 'no error log' MySQL instance to pastebin.com the complete TEXT results of A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; and C) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; and share the links here, I will help you get your error log functional. Also still would like the see STS from 'GeneralStats'; please.

Comment: STS from 'GeneralStats': https://pastebin.com/raw/Sy8Kmbz3

I dont know if this is right, because im not familiar with mysql :C
Are the other querys just like this?

Comment: The posted GeneralStats result is fine.  From your MySQL Command Prompt, yes, just use the different requests for A) B) and C) and paste the results as TEXT into pastebin.com as rows of data and share the 3 links assigned by pastebin.com, please.

Comment: A) https://pastebin.com/raw/HTcy5tJn 
B) https://pastebin.com/raw/iMmawTXP
C) https://pastebin.com/raw/VUWvLp3w

Comment: Analysis in process.  Thank you for the data to analyze.

Comment: How much RAM is on your server?  Cores/Cpu's? Any SSD or NVME for data storage?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.

Ram: 8 GB
100% SSD
4 cores

Comment: I have 200 GB 100% SSD, for specification :D

Comment: Do you still need assistance with your very slow server? Sorry, I just saw your June 23 comments.